# Debug Watch app while parent iphone application in in background

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, apple-watch, xcode6.3

I am not able to attach watch app process into debugger while running from iPhone app.

I am following below steps.

1. Run iPhone app from Xcode in iPhone.
2. Make app in background.
3. Open watch app in apple watch.

Now I am doing Debug -> Attach to process. in that list apple watch process is not showing..

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have only played with the Simulator (watch not arrived), but you better launch the watch app using Xcode and then open the iPhone app manually.

Xcode will only attach to one of them, so may need to debug one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the WatchKit app target from Xcode, then launch the iPhone app manually or from Xcode. Note that you can attach to the iPhone app while attached to the WatchKit app to debug both at the same time.